# Why is xargs -n 1 so slow for long lines

Tags: xargs

A line generated with command `echo {,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}` contains 8191 words, which is 114687 characters: 106497 dots and 8190 spaces.

Why does splitting it with `| xargs -n 1` take computational ages? On my PC it's 8 seconds.

Background story.

Kidding around with bash brace expansion I've stumbled upon a fancy issue.
I was checking time of bash brace expansion on the example problem: print strings of one, two and so on up to 'n' (=13) dots each in new line avoiding explicit loops and variables. I've come up with this somewhat slow solution:

```
$ time echo {,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·} | xargs -n 1 | sort -u
·
··
···
····
·····
······
·······
········
·········
··········
···········
············
·············

real    0m8.800s
user    0m0.188s
sys     0m0.748s
```

I assumed it was caused by `sort` performance, so I've checked a solution without sorting:

```
$ time echo {,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·} | xargs -n 1 | awk '{if (!a[$0]) {print $0} ; a[$0]=$0}'
·
··
···
····
·····
······
·······
········
·········
··········
···········
············
·············

real    0m8.250s
user    0m0.152s
sys     0m0.784s
```

Which was a bit faster. Expansion itself was surprisingly fast:

```
time echo {,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·} > /dev/null

real    0m0.024s
user    0m0.020s
sys     0m0.004s
```

It was 0m0.250s when printing wall of dots to console, but that's the output which usually is slow compared to computation. So I checked how long does splitting to lines take:

```
time echo {,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·}{,·} | xargs -n 1 > /dev/null 

real    0m8.551s
user    0m0.096s
sys     0m0.724s
```

What is `xargs` doing all that time?

Comment: xargs is running /bin/echo 2**13-1 times. Your pattern generates these 8191 combinations and then you ask xargs to echo them using a process per combination. It has nothing to do with the length of the line, just that you have 8000 things to process

Answer (score 7, accepted):

xargs is slow, because it runs `/bin/echo` 8191 times.

Use `| tr -s " " "\n"` instead.

Comment: That's even clearly stated in its documentation, lol. _This manual page documents the GNU version of xargs. xargs reads items from the standard input, delimited by blanks (which can be protected with double or single quotes or a backslash) or newlines, and executes the command_ **(default is /bin/echo)** _one or more times with any initial-arguments followed by items read from standard input. Blank lines on the standard input are ignored._

Comment: Just checked that `time for x in {1..8191} ; do /bin/echo -n ; done` runs for 12 seconds, while `time for x in {1..8191} ; do echo -n ; done` runs in no time. Again, process spawning has hit me.

Comment: run `type echo`

Comment: I did. `echo` is fast shell built-in, while `/bin/echo` is slow plain executable which runs as separate process. BTW: it seems that `xargs` uses `vfork` and `execve` to spawn processes, which is faster (8s) than my `for` loop (12s). Check this out: https://opensource.apple.com/source/shell_cmds/shell_cmds-116/xargs/xargs.c label `exec:`.